# I cannot scrape a table from a website with usual web scraping tools

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrape a table from a website with Python but for some reason all of my known methods have failed. There's a table at
https://www.nbc4i.com/news/state-news/535-new-cases-of-covid-19-reported-in-ohio-schools-in-past-week/
with 45 pages. I have tried to scrape it with using: requests, requests-html (rendered it), BeautifulSoup and selenium as well. This is one of my codes, I won't copy here all of those I tried, methods are similar just with different Python libraries:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()
page = session.get('https://www.nbc4i.com/news/state-news/535-new-cases-of-covid-19-reported-in-ohio-schools-in-past-week/')
page.html.render(timeout=120)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml') #also tried with page.text and 'html.parser' and all permutations
table = soup.find_all(id='table')
```

My table variable is an empty list here and it shouldn't be. I've tried to find any other web elements within the table with selenium, I tried to find by class, xpath as well, but all of these have failed to find the table or any part of it. I scraped quite few similar websites with these methods and I have never had a problem before this one.
Any ideas, please?

Comment: Table is in an iframe. Must switch to the iframe then "table" content is queryable.

Comment: Yes, I can see now, thanks, bud. This is when I learn html through web scraping and I'm lack of some basic knowledge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd see that the result table is in an iframe. You can extract the information directly from the source of the iframe:

> https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/3894531/embed?auto=1

Here the code that should save the result onto a .csv file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

def get_rows(driver):
    """
    returns rows from a page
    
    Returns:
    Dict
    """
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tr body-row']")))
    rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tr body-row']")
    table_info= {
        'Rank': [],
        'County':[],
        'School/District':[],
        'Type':[],
        'Total cases':[],
        'Student cases':[],
        'Staff cases':[]
    }
    
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'td')
        for col, index in enumerate(table_info):
            table_info[index].append(cols[col].text)

    return table_info

# path to chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chromedriver\94\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/3894531/embed?auto=1")


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(get_rows(driver))

for _ in range(44):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="pagination-btn next"]'))).click()
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_dict(get_rows(driver))])

print(df)
df.to_csv('COVID-19_cases_reported_in_Ohio_schools.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The table content is in an iframe and need to switch to the iframe page. See [API docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames).

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://www.nbc4i.com/news/state-news/535-new-cases-of-covid-19-reported-in-ohio-schools-in-past-week/'
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
try:
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
            '//div[@class="ns-block-custom-html"]/div/iframe'))
    # table content is now in the driver context
    while True:
        table = driver.find_element(By.ID, "table")
        for elt in table.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "body-row"):
            items = [td.text for td in elt.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "td")]
            # add code to append each of row of data to CSV file, database, etc.
            print(items)
        next_btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'next')        
        if 'disabled' in next_btn.get_attribute('class'):
            # no more > done with pagination
            break
        next_btn.click() # click next button for next set of items
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

**Outputs:**

```
['1', 'Delaware', 'Olentangy Local', 'Public District', '38', '31', '7']
...
['446', 'Muskingum', 'West Muskingum Local', 'Public District', '1', '1', '0']
```